# Pointer to Static

Tags: c++, arrays, string, pointers

The class `Student` have a static member `Year` which is a pointer to `std::string` that should point to a dynamically allocated array.

```
class Student
{
private:
    string name;
    int year;
    string semester;
    int AmtClass;
    static string *Year[4];

    //Skipping the public members
};

string *Student::Year[4] = { "Freshman", "Sophomore", "Junior", "senior" };
```

Problem occurs when trying to initialize `Year`:

```
ERROR: Cannot convert 'const char*' to 'std::string*' in initialization
```

Why do I get the error?

Comment: You really need to clarify what you are asking here. As it stands this does not make a lot of sense

Comment: what part of the error message you don't understand?

Answer (score 3):

```
struct A
{
    static std::string *cohort;
};

std::string * A::cohort = new std::string[4];
```

It is not clear why you want to allocate dynamically the array. You could use 
`std::array<std::string, 4>` or `std::dynarray<std::string>`

As you updated your post then either you should write

```
std::string * Student::Year = new std::string[4] { "Freshman", "Sophomore", "Junior", "senior" };
```

Or

```
struct Student
{
    static std::string Year[];
};


std::string Student::Year[4] = { "Freshman", "Sophomore", "Junior", "senior" };
```